# Unity ML-Agents Running Very Slowly

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, pytorch, ml-agent

Using the Python API, whether I run using a build or in the Editor the simulation is much slower than when using the provided `mlagents-learn` methods. I'm running something similar to [this](https://github.com/xkiwilabs/DDPG-using-PyTorch-and-ML-Agents), using a PyTorch implementation of DDPG and CUDA 9.0. Is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got to the `Academy`'s proprieties and make sure that the value of `Time Scale` in the `Inference Configuration` is equals to the `Training Configuration`'s one.

For other info check the official documentation of ML-Agents at [Learning-Environment-Design-Academy](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/blob/master/docs/Learning-Environment-Design-Academy.md)

Answer (score 0):

To use deep reinforcement learning models you have to use unityagents 0.4, and in 0.4 version how are you using mlagents-learn. It supports different commands.